# Getting back variables from an interpolated string

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string in a UITableViewCell with variables.
eg: var toDoItem: String = String ("the name: \(name) and quantity:\(quantity) and color:\(color)"

this is displayed as a string in the tableview cell. 
the names are added to the [String] of Names and quantity is added to the int array [Int] of quantity and so on.

If I facilitate deleting the cell, I should be able to delete the name, quantity and the color for that row. But as this is a string, I must be able to access these variables individually to deduct from the relevant arrays.

How can I get access to the variables, given an interpolated string?

Thanks.

Comment: Taking something from a string into a specific type is called parsing. I wouldn't do it this way, I'd store a bunch of variables from when the cell was created in the first place. But if you have to, you can just split the string and parse the parts into the appropriate variables.

Comment: To retrieve values from a `String`, you can us regular expressions. See documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/ and a nice tutorial

Answer (score 0):

If your values are all in the form "key:value" followed by a space or by the end of the string then this function might work for you:

```
import Foundation

func valueFromKeyInString(key:String, string:String) -> String? {
  if let keyRange = string.rangeOfString(key) {
    let endIndex = string.rangeOfString(" ", options: [], range:
      (keyRange.startIndex..<string.endIndex), locale: NSLocale.currentLocale())?.startIndex ??
      string.endIndex
      return string.substringWithRange(keyRange.endIndex..<endIndex)
  }
  return nil
}

// how it's used:
let string = "the name:bob and quantity:12 and color:red"
let name = valueFromKeyInString("name:", string: string)         // => "bob"
let quantity = valueFromKeyInString("quantity:", string: string) // => "12"
let color = valueFromKeyInString("color:", string: string)       // => "red"
```

You can then use those strings to convert into the values you need.

Regex will also work but this is a fairly simple parse if you can be sure of the formatting of your string. Of course, if you have access to the actual values then you should try to get those rather than parsing a string.

Answer (score 0):

@Carlos is right - you don't want to parse the data out of the presentation string you have created.  You must already have the variables `name`, `quantity` and `color` stored somewhere that you used in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

If the data is already stored in an array, you can access it when you delete the cell, using `indexPath` to find the data in your array.

Here's an example from one I did earlier, where my data is held in an array `sourceAlbumNames`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return sourceAlbumNames.count;
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell


    cell.textLabel?.text = sourceAlbumNames[indexPath.row] as String

    return cell
}
```

I guess you already have something like this for the delete

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete) {
        // handle delete (by removing the data from your array and updating the tableview)

         sourceAlbumNames.removeAtIndex(indexPath!.row)
         tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: I have them in arrays. But indexPath.row returns a UITableViewCell object. How to go from there? Can you give an example?